# Blank lines when reading multiple text files

Tags: vb.net

I have a small section of code that reads all the text files in a directory and writes them to the console.  This works fine, except sometimes It writes a blank line.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
For Each xFile In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Test1", "*.txt", False)
            Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(xFile)
                While r.Peek() >= 0
                    line = r.ReadLine
                    Console.WriteLine(line)
                End While
            End Using
        Next

End Sub
```

Below is a sample of the output:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3

Line4
Line5
Line6
```

There is not any pattern to the line space, and it happens in the middle of files, not at the end.

1) Why are there random blank lines
2) How can I get them to stop showing up?

Comment: Try to use of File.ReadAllLines. it returns string array

Comment: Tried that, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some invisible characters there. Can you try

```
Dim noEmptyLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(Function(l) l.Trim() <> String.Empty).ToArray()
```

This should give you array without empty lines.